# Special select widget returning form errors when submitted ("no data")

Tags: web2py

I need some help to have a widget work correctly in a web2py app.
By the way, once corrected, I think it could be useful to other users...

I built a SELECT widget to expose regions and their sub-regions ('departement')  so that the user may have the choice.
For instance: a region A is divided into departement 11 and departement 12 and so on.
The user can choose either a region or a specific departement (sub-region).

The widget works correctly except that when submitted, the form returns errors:
form.errors: "r_name: no data".
Below is a working example to show the problem.

Could anybody help me having this widget work correctly without returning errors, please. Since I don't understand what's wrong...
I would greatly appreciate your kind help.
Thanks a lot in advance.
Sorry for the formatting, but it's the first time I post here ... ;)

Dominique

in the model:

```
     db.define_table('region',
Field('r_name', 'string', length=250, required=True)
)  
db.define_table('departement',
Field('d_name', 'string', length=250, required=True),
Field('d_code', 'string', length=3, required=True),
Field('d_region', db.region)
)
db.define_table('region',
Field('r_name', 'string', length=250, required=True)
)  
db.define_table('departement',
Field('d_name', 'string', length=250, required=True),
Field('d_code', 'string', length=3, required=True),
Field('d_region', db.region)
)

def region_widget(f,v,_class= "options"):
"""
Widget  that shows regions and departements in a SELECT.
Can be used with SQLFORM and SQLFORM.factory
Usage:
db.region.r_name.widget = region_dptt_select_widget
"""
region_dptt = db(db.region.id==db.departement.d_region)\
                .select(db.region.r_name, db.region.id, db.departement.d_name, db.departement.d_code, db.departement.id, \
                orderby=db.region.r_name, cache=(cache.ram,6))

   def prepare_select(rows):
    """
    Creates a list of tuples to be used in the SELECT helper:
    ['Region A', OPTGROUP('SubRegion 1','SubRegion 2', 'SubRegion 3'),
    'Region B', OPTGROUP('SubRegion 4','SubRegion 5', 'SubRegion 6')]
    """
    l_r=[]
    for row in rows:
        r = row.region.r_name
        if row.region.r_name not in l_r:
            l_r.append(row.region.r_name)
    interm_list=[]
    for reg in l_r:
       l_sr=[]
       for row in rows:
            if reg == row.region.r_name:
                reg_id = row.region.id
                dep = row.departement.d_code + ' ' + row.departement.d_name
                dep_id = row.departement.id
                l_sr.append(OPTION(dep,_value=row.departement.d_code)) 
       option_reg = OPTION(reg, _value= 'R'+str(reg_id))
       interm_list.append((option_reg,l_sr))
    res=[]
    for reg, l_sr in interm_list:
        res.append(reg)
        res.append(OPTGROUP(*l_sr))
    return res
return SELECT(*prepare_select(region_dptt),
              **dict(_name='region_to_search', _value=v, _id='region_to_search', _type = 'string', _class="options"))
```

in the controller:

```
  def test():
db.region.r_name.widget = region_widget
fields=['r_name']
labels = {'r_name':T('')}
form= SQLFORM(db.region, fields = fields, labels = labels)
a=None
if form.accepts(request.vars, session, formname='test_form', dbio=False):
    a = form.vars
elif form.errors:
    a = form.errors
return dict(form=form, a = a)

def insertions():# TO RUN one time to fill regions and departments in the db
db.region.insert(r_name="Region A")
db.region.insert(r_name="Region B")
db.departement.insert(d_name="SubRegion 1", d_code="11", d_region=1)
db.departement.insert(d_name="SubRegion 2", d_code="12",  d_region=1)
db.departement.insert(d_name="SubRegion 3", d_code="21",  d_region=2)
db.departement.insert(d_name="SubRegion 4", d_code="22",  d_region=2)
db.departement.insert(d_name="SubRegion 5", d_code="25",  d_region=2)
db.departement.insert(d_name="SubRegion 6", d_code="26",  d_region=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your widget sets `_name='region_to_search'`, but SQLFORM expects the form input field name (and therefore the associated variable in `request.vars`) to be the same as the name of the field in the db table used to generate the form (which is 'r_name'). So, try changing your widget code to `_name='r_name'`.